# check whitespace in string in inductive step of function in haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to count the length of string excluding whitespaces.
I can't use length,filter and if-else. Only recursion.
My current code is:

```
countLetters :: String -> Int
countLetters "" = 0
countLetters str = 1+ countLetters(tail str)
```

What i tried to do,

```
countLetters :: String -> Int
countLetters "" = 0
countLetters (" ",xs) = 0 + countLetters(xs)
countLetters str = 1+ countLetters(tail str)
```

But what i got instead is:

```
Couldn't match type `([Char], String)' with `[Char]'
  Expected type: String
    Actual type: ([Char], String)
In the pattern: (" ", xs)
  In an equation for `countLetters':
      countLetters (" ", xs) = 0 + countLetters (xs)
```

I also tried removing the extra inductive step and enumerating the condition,

```
fromEnum head str!=" "
```

So if head of the string is whitespace then the value would be 1 but != is not a valid operator.
even == would yield,

```
   head str == " "
<interactive>:22:13: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
    * In the second argument of `(==)', namely `" "'
      In the expression: head str == " "
      In an equation for `it': it = head str == " "
```

So Please help me find another method.

Comment: your second snippet is very close, you've just got the pattern wrong. A list with head `x` and tail `xs` is written `(x:xs)`, not `(x, xs)`. (Also, `" "` will not work for the head as it's a String not a Char - hopefully you can figure out how to fix that yourself.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond I wrote `countLetters (x:xs) = if x==' ' then 0 + countLetters(xs) else 1 + countLetters(xs)`  and this works but i still don't understand how to do this without if-else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made two mistakes here. First of all the "cons" of a list uses `(:)` as data constructor, so you work with `(" ":xs)`, not `(" ",xs)`.

Furthermore a `String` is a *list* of `Char`s, so that means that the elements are `Char`s, not `String`s, therefore you should use `' '`, not <s>`" "`</s>:

```
countLetters :: String -> Int
countLetters "" = 0
countLetters (' ':xs) = countLetters xs
countLetters str = 1 + countLetters (tail str)
```

Typically it is also better to work with pattern matching instead of working with `head` and `tail`, since `tail` raises an error for an empty list, and by using pattern matching, we know that the list is not empty:

```
countLetters :: String -> Int
countLetters "" = 0
countLetters (x:xs)
    | x == ' ' = countLetters xs
    | otherwise = 1 + countLetters xs
```